# how to remove weird vertical rectangle area when push and pop

Tags: ios

I set a background image for both a navigation controller root view controller and a pushed view controller, but as you can see in the gif, there is a weird vertical rectangle area when push and pop, and the animation is kind of laggy.

[image: the problem description]

```
private var isCustomBackgroundOn:Bool {
    set {
        if newValue {
            if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: Constants.homeVCBackgroundImageURL) {
                backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            } else {
                backgroundImageView.image = nil
                self.isCustomBackgroundOn = false
                self.isBlurEffectOn = false
            }
        } else{
            self.isBlurEffectOn = false
            backgroundImageView.image = nil
        }
    }
    get {
        if let isOn = Constants.defaults.value(forKey: Constants.isCustomBackgroundOnKey) as? Bool {
            return isOn
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

lazy var backgroundImageView:UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    // 如果document文件夹有图片的话，加载图片
    let url = Constants.homeVCBackgroundImageURL

    // 只有当用户打开自定义背景图开关，才从Document文件夹尝试加载图片
    if self.isCustomBackgroundOn {
        if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            v.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    }

    v.frame = self.view.bounds
    return v
}()

private var isBlurEffectOn:Bool {
    set {
        Constants.defaults.setValue(newValue, forKey: Constants.isBlurOnKey)
    }
    get {
        if let isOn = Constants.defaults.value(forKey: Constants.isBlurOnKey) as? Bool {
            return isOn
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

private var vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
lazy var blurView:UIVisualEffectView = {
    // 先创建第一层的UIVisualEffectView(用blur效果)
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    // 再创建第二层的UIVisualEffectView(用使用第一层blur效果创建的vibrancy效果)
    let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect)
    self.vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)
    self.vibrancyEffectView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    return blurEffectView
}()

private func setBackGroundView() {
    // 只有用户设置了背景图，才将模糊视图添加到主界面
    self.vibrancyEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.blurView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.backgroundImageView.removeFromSuperview()

    if self.backgroundImageView.image != nil {
        if isBlurEffectOn {
            // 将第二层UIVisualEffectView添加到第一层的contentView中
            self.view.insertSubview(self.blurView, belowSubview: self.tableView)
            // 加载背景图
            self.view.insertSubview(self.backgroundImageView, belowSubview: self.blurView)
        } else {
            // 加载背景图
            self.view.insertSubview(self.backgroundImageView, belowSubview: self.tableView)
        }
    }
}
```

These are the codes for the pushed ViewController. setBackgroundView is called in its viewDidLoad. There are mainly three views from top to bottom, a tableview whose backgroundColor is set to clear, a UIVisualEffectView as default, a UIImageView uses as the background image.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using. Also you need to look at things like the transparency that appears to be present. Could that be your issue?

Comment: @drekka, yes, my code screenshots are posted, please have a look. The view hierarchy is like this, from top to bottom, tableView, UIVisualEffectView, UIImageView. The root view background is set to white, visualEffectView is as default, and the top tableView is clear

Comment: Do not post codes as screenshots, copy & paste into your question please.

Comment: @Raptor, okay, changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clip your image :

`backgroundImageView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Thank you, Sir! This solved my problem, much appreciated!